# Having an array of parameters, replacing them to %s's in an order

Tags: php

I have a static class like this.

```
<?php

class Language
{
    public static $language = array();
    var $config;

    function __construct($config)
    {
        switch(strtoupper($config['LANGUAGE']))
        {
            case 'ENGLISH':
                self::setEnglish();
                break;

            case 'TURKISH':
                self::setTurkish();
                break;

            default:
                self::setEnglish();
        }
    }

    public static function setEnglish()
    {
        self::$language = array(

                'CHAIN_VALIDATOR_INITIALIZED' => 'ChainValidator initialized!',
                'ERROR_FUNCTION_RETURNED_FALSE' => 'A function returned false.',
            );
    }

    public static function setTurkish()
    {
        self::$language = array(

                'CHAIN_VALIDATOR_INITIALIZED' => 'ChainValidator çalışıyor!',
                'ERROR_FUNCTION_RETURNED_FALSE' => 'Bir fonksiyon false döndürdü.',
            );
    }

    public static function getLanguage($key)
    {
        return isset(self::$language[$key]) ? self::$language[$key] : $key;
    }
}

?>
```

It is being used like this,

```
Language::getLanguage('CHAIN_VALIDATOR_INITIALIZED')
```

but I have to pass more parameters. Similar to this,

```
Language::getLanguage('CHAIN_VALIDATOR_INITIALIZED', array(__FUNCTION__))
```

These parameters should be passed in an order, like %s. Final look should look like this:

```
 "A function returned false" to;
 "%s function returned false"

 And output would be;
 "myLovelyFunction() returned false" (the first array parameter, which is __FUNCTION__)
```

Sounds like piece of cake my brain stopped atm.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func_array](http://docs.php.net/call_user_func_array) and [sprintf](http://docs.php.net/sprintf) for that, e.g.

```
<?php
foo();

function foo() {
    $text = format('CHAIN_VALIDATOR_INITIALIZED', array(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__));
    echo $text;
}

function format($key, $params) {
    $format = '%s@%s: function returned false'; // =getLanguage($key)
    array_unshift($params, $format);
    return call_user_func_array('sprintf', $params);
}
```

prints

```
foo@5: function returned false
```

Comment: I've also posted my solution a while ago. Which one is more logical to use? Mine seems a bit easier to be read, but using str_replace, so it may cause performance related problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think [vsprintf](http://php.net/vsprintf) does just what you want. It is basically a sprintf that accepts arguments as an array.

```
$string = "%s %s blabla";
$params = array('foo', 'bar');

$output = vsprintf($string, $params);
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know that php has that function ,too. Way better than using call_user_func_array(sprintf,...)

Answer (score 0):

Changing my getLanguage function solved it. If anyone needs it, here is the solution.

```
public static function getLanguage($key, $parameters = null)
{
    $string = self::$language[$key];

    if(is_array($parameters))
    {
        foreach ($parameters as $k => $v)
        {
            $string = str_ireplace('%s', $v, $string);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Try your solution with more than one parameter ;-)

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the fail. :p